# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present error from JS to Cloudflare Workers

Tags: javascript, cors, cloudflare-workers, edge-function

I have an edge function in Javascript on Cloudflare Workers. The only thing it does is to check a specific header and return a JSON containing a value accordingly

See code below

```
async function handleRequest(request) {

  const url = new URL(request.url);

  const psk_db = await KV_STORAGE.get(request.headers.get(PRESHARED_AUTH_HEADER_KEY));


  if (psk_db === null) {
    return new Response("Access denied", { status: 404 });
  }
  else{
    //calculate number

    //return JSON
    const data = {
      pswd: psk_db,
    };

    json = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
  }

  return new Response(json, {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': url.origin,
      },
    })

}



addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request));
});
```

Now, the function works fine on the cloudflare test envirovment but when I try to request from an html page with a button that run this javascript function

```
function RequestCode() {
  const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const url = "https://code-return.dev-malv.workers.dev";

  Http.open("GET", url);
  Http.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  Http.setRequestHeader("X-Custom-PSK", "m_custom_key");
  Http.send();

  Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
    console.log(Http.responseText);
  };
}
```

I got the error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'my_workers_url' from origin 'null' has
> been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
> pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
> present on the requested resource.

I have added on both side the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` at `*` but it doesn't work

What can I do to avoid the error?

Already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i) but it doesn't solve the issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was that the worker didn't answer to OPTIONS request.

The solution was to handle these type of requests with

```
if (request.method === "OPTIONS") {
    return handleOptions(request)
  }
```

and

```
function handleOptions(request) {
  if (request.headers.get("Origin") !== null &&
      request.headers.get("Access-Control-Request-Method") !== null &&
      request.headers.get("Access-Control-Request-Headers") !== null) {
    // Handle CORS pre-flight request.
    return new Response(null, {
      headers: corsHeaders
    })
  } else {
    // Handle standard OPTIONS request.
    return new Response(null, {
      headers: {
        "Allow": "GET, OPTIONS",
      }
    })
  }
}
```

with

```
const corsHeaders = {
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, OPTIONS",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
}
```

Clearly `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` adding only the

Reference https://community.cloudflare.com/t/handling-preflight-requests/30260/3